# Extracting tweets from a location based on profile in tweepy

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter, tweepy, twitter-streaming-api

I'm developing a piece of code whereby I want to track a key word using the Twitter streaming API.

Obviously, when I track the key word I get global results. I'm aware you cant stream both key words and locations simulatiously due to the API parameter requirements.

Instead I plan on only saving the streamed tweets which list their profile location as being in a certain city (London in this case).

Currently I'm trying the following

```
def on_status(self,status):
    try:
        locations=status.user.location
        if locations == ['London']:
           #Save to database
        else:
             pass
```

However, this isn't saving any tweets which contain the profile location as London

Comment: Could you post the output of the line `print(locations)`?

Comment: It doesnt print anything as it isn't picking up any tweets where locations == 'london'. I know there will be tweets with the as a location as my keyword is "weather"

Comment: When the print is in the else statement, it prints locations correctly. Whats annoying is that I can see some of these are London!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should change this line:

```
if locations == ['London']: // status.user.location returns a string, not a list!
```

to:

```
if locations == 'London':
```

Your code didn't work because `status.user.location` returned a string and you compared this string with a list. That couldn't work.

And one other thing: since `status.user.location` can be "London, England" it's better to do some normalization and check on substring inclusion:

```
if 'london' in locations.lower():
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! cant believe I missed that!